# Breeze Partial initializer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js, breeze

I have a Single Page Application that is working pretty well so far but I have run into an issue I am unable to figure out. I am using breeze to populate a list of projects to be displayed in a table. There is way more info than what I actually need so I am doing a projection on the data. I want to add a knockout computed onto the entity. So to accomplish this I registered and entity constructor like so...

```
metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(entityNames.project, function () { this.isPartial = false; }, initializeProject);
```

The initializeProject function uses some of the values in the project to determine what the values should be for the computed. For example if the Project.Type == "P" then the rowClass should = "Red".

The problem I am having is that all the properties of Project are null except for the ProjNum which happens to be the key. I believe the issue is because I am doing the projection because I have registered other initializers for other types and they work just fine. Is there a way to make this work?

EDIT: I thought I would just add a little more detail for clarification. The values of all the properties are set to knockout observables, when I interrogate the properties using the javascript debugger in Chrome the _latestValue of any of the properties is null. The only property that is set is the ProjNum which is also the entity key.

EDIT2: Here is the client side code that does the projection

```
var getProjectPartials = function (projectObservable, username, forceRemote) {
    var p1 = new breeze.Predicate("ProjManager", "==", username);
    var p2 = new breeze.Predicate("ApprovalStatus", "!=", "X");
    var p3 = new breeze.Predicate("ApprovalStatus", "!=", "C");

    var select = 'ProjNum,Title,Type,ApprovalStatus,CurrentStep,StartDate,ProjTargetDate,CurTargDate';

    var isQaUser = cookies.getCookie("IsQaUser");

    if (isQaUser == "True") {
        p1 = new breeze.Predicate("QAManager", "==", username);
        select = select + ',QAManager';
    } else {
        select = select + ',ProjManager';
    }

    var query = entityQuery
        .from('Projects')
        .where(p1.and(p2).and(p3))
        .select(select);

    if (!forceRemote) {
        var p = getLocal(query);
        if (p.length > 1) {
            projectObservable(p);
            return Q.resolve();
        }
    }

    return manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceeded).fail(queryFailed);

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        var list = partialMapper.mapDtosToEntities(
            manager,
            data.results,
            model.entityNames.project,
            'ProjNum'
        );
        if (projectObservable) {
            projectObservable(list);
        }
        log('Retrieved projects using breeze', data, true);
    }
};
```

and the code for the partialMapper.mapDtosToEntities function.

```
var defaultExtension = { isPartial: true };

function mapDtosToEntities(manager,dtos,entityName,keyName,extendWith) {
    return dtos.map(dtoToEntityMapper);

    function dtoToEntityMapper(dto) {
        var keyValue = dto[keyName];
        var entity = manager.getEntityByKey(entityName, keyValue);
        if (!entity) {
            extendWith = $.extend({}, extendWith || defaultExtension);
            extendWith[keyName] = keyValue;
            entity = manager.createEntity(entityName, extendWith);
        }
        mapToEntity(entity, dto);
        entity.entityAspect.setUnchanged();
        return entity;
    }

    function mapToEntity(entity, dto) {
        for (var prop in dto) {
            if (dto.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                entity[prop](dto[prop]);
            }
        }
        return entity;
    }
}
```

EDIT3: Looks like it was my mistake. I found the error when I looked closer at initializeProject. Below is what the function looked like before i fixed it.

```
function initializeProject(project) {
    project.rowClass = ko.computed(function() {
        if (project.Type == "R") {
            return "project-list-item info";
        } else if (project.Type == "P") {
            return "project-list-item error";
        }
        return "project-list-item";
    });
}
```

the issue was with project.Type I should have used project.Type() since it is an observable. It is a silly mistake that I have made too many times since starting this project.

EDIT4: Inside initializeProject some parts are working and others aren't. When I try to access project.ProjTargetDate() I get null, same with project.StartDate(). Because of the Null value I get an error thrown from the moment library as I am working with these dates to determine when a project is late. I tried removing the select from the client query and the call to the partial entity mapper and when I did that everything worked fine.

Comment: I think I know what's wrong but I can't be sure until I see your query. Is it a server-side projection or a client-side projection? If (as I suspect) it's client-side projection, what are you doing to copy the projected values that are returned from the server into new instances of the `Project` type?

Comment: @Ward I have edited my original post to include the client side query and the partialMapper function I use to map the data to entities.

Comment: Later I'll explain how to do this much more simply. Let's get this working first. I still don't know at which point your properties are null. After `createEntity`? After `mapToEntity` What does `initProject` do? What is `defaultExtension`? Is `extendWith` always empty (as it appears to be)? You know there are kind of too many moving parts here. Can you start from something simple that works and then add complexity slowly?

Comment: @Ward thanks for your help. Even though you didnt give me the solution directly your questions helped me find the error. I have modified my question with details on how I fixed it.

Comment: @Ward looks like I jumped the gun saying everything was working. still some small issues with date fields not having values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be getting closer. I think a few more guard clauses in your `initializeProject` method would help and, when working with Knockout, one is constantly battling the issue of parentheses.

Btw, I highly recommend the [Knockout Context Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof) plugin for Chrome for diagnosing binding problems.

### Try toType()

You're working very hard with your DTO mapping, following along with John's code from his course. Since then there's a new way to get projection data into an entity: add `toType(...)` to the end of the query like this:

```
var query = entityQuery
        .from('Projects')
        .where(p1.and(p2).and(p3))
        .select(select)
        .toType('Project'); // cast to Project
```

It won't solve everything but you may be able to do away with the dto mapping.

### Consider DTOs on the server

I should have pointed this out first. If you're always cutting this data down to size, why not define the client-facing model to suit your client. Create DTO classes of the right shape(s) and project into them on the server before sending data over the wire.

You can also build metadata to match those DTOs so that `Project` on the client has exactly the properties it should have there ... and no more.

I'm writing about this now. Should have a page on it in a week or so.

Comment: Are those DTO classes part of the EF model on the server? If yes, then what about the (empty) tables in the db?

Comment: @pawel - I don't understand your question. DTOs, by definition, are never part of the EF model.

Comment: This solved my issues with getting null values on my initializer. There is one thing I will mention that might be of use to others. When querying against the local cache (using a projection) the computed values created in the initializer(rowClass for example) need to be added to the select statement in order to use them in the view.

Comment: Wow, the .toType("type") just fixed what I spent way to long trying to figure out... I didn't realize it wasn't running my constructor and initializers correctly without this. Thank you so much!